# remove array elements between two numbers using jquery

Tags: jquery

Have to delete the array elements in the range of elements from another array

My first array

```
var arr = ['900','930','1000','1030','1100','1130','1200','1230','1300','1330','1400','1430','1500']
```

another result array is

```
var data =['900','1000','1300','1400']
```

my output array should be

```
output = ['1030','1100','1130','1200','1230','1430','1500','1530']
```

i tried using for loop and slice but unable to delete the range of elements.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(jQuery.inArray(data[i], arr) !== -1){
      arr.splice(data[i]);
    }                           
}
```

Comment: By range, do you mean the numbers between pairs of elements in `data`?

Comment: yes  @RejithRKrishnan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. However it won't work with strings, so I've changed everything to numbers:

```js
var arr = [900,930,1000,1030,1100,1130,1200,1230,1300,1330,1400,1430,1500];

/** create an array of ranges **/
var ranges = [900,1000,1300,1400].reduce(function(tupples, item, index) {
    if(index % 2 === 0) {
      tupples.push([item]);
    } else {
      tupples[tupples.length - 1].push(item);
    }

    return tupples;
}, []);

/** filter the original array to get a new array of items that are not in one of the ranges **/
var result = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return ranges.every(function(range) {
      return item < range[0] || item > range[1];
    });
});

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></id>
```

p.s. if you want to use numbers in strings instead of numbers -
replace this - `return item < range[0] || item > range[1];`
with this - `return Number(item) < Number(range[0]) || Number(item) > Number(range[1]);`

Comment: thanks for reply.its returning ['930','1030','1100','1130','1200','1230',1330','1430','1500']..output should be ['1030','1100','1130','1200','1230','1430','1500'']

Comment: Try again. It won't work with strings, so you'll have to change everything to numbers.